# Convergence of Integrals implies almost everywhere convergence of functions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral, pointwise-convergence

I'm wondering whether the following statement holds:

Let $f_n,f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+_0$ be functions with $\int f_n(x) dx = \int f(x) dx=1$ and for every bounded and countinuous function $g\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ the following integral-convergence
$$\int g(x) \cdot f_n(x) dx \rightarrow_n \int g(x) \cdot f(x) dx$$ holds. Then it follows that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere.

Intuitively the statement looks false, but I can't find a counterexample. If it doesn't hold: changes the further assumption that the $f_n,f$ have to be continuous anything?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classical counterexample is $$f_n(x):=\bigl(1+\sin(2\pi nx)\bigr)\mathbf1_{\{x\in(0,1)\}},$$
and $$f(x):=\mathbf1_{\{x\in(0,1)\}}.$$
We have $\int f_n=\int f=1$ and, for every bounded continuous $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $\int f_ng\to\int fg$ as $n\to\infty$ (e.g., by Riemann–Lebesgue lemma). However, $(f_n)_{n\ge1}$ does not converge at all.

Comment: Could you clarify the reasoning meant by Riemann-Lebesuge lemma? We identify $\sin(2\pi nx) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\lbrace x \in (0,1) \rbrace}$ as a Fourier-transform of a $L^1$ function, thus it converges to 0 for $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @fix foxi: [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) gives you directly that $\int_0^1g(x)\sin(2\pi nx)\,\mathrm dx\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! Regarding the second part of my question: Do you know, whether tightening the assumptions further to "$f_n, f$ are continuous" changes anything?

Comment: I think it does not change anything. You can replace $\mathbf 1_{\{x\in(0,1)\}}$ by, e.g., $\frac12\mathrm e^{-|x|}$ (or even $\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$ if you want $\mathcal C^\infty$ densities).

Comment: Yes, but we can not change our $f_n$ to a continuous one that easily, do we?
On secound thought: We may replace the $1$ in $f_n$ by a non-negative $C_c^{\infty}$ function $\phi$ with compact support $\subset (0,1)$ and with $\int \phi =1$. Thus we do not have a jump at 0 or 1 but the properties from before all remain true.
Many thanks!

Comment: You could also replace the $\mathbf1$ in $f_n$ by $\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$, right?

Comment: I do think, we forgot the assumption that $f_n \geq 0,$ which wouldn't be true anymore. Right now, I do not see a fast fix of that...

Comment: I may be tired, but $1+\sin(2\pi nx)$ is always $\ge0$, so $(1+\sin(2\pi nx))\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}\ge0$ for any $x$…

Comment: Yes, that's true. I thought about replacing the 1 in the parenthesises not about the multiplication. Then it is still integrable. I need to check whether it has integral equals 1.

Comment: *Hint.* The integral of an odd, integrable function is $0$. ;)

Comment: Just realized that. Thank you very much for the help and solution of the question!